# Monodroid "Hello-World" for Visual Studio 2010 fails

Tags: visual-studio-2010, deployment, xamarin.android

I tried to creat the "Hello-World" in mono for android using visual studio 2010. I followed the instructions given here: http://mono-android.net/Tutorials/Hello_World
It worked fine until this stage:

"Visual Studio will now package up your application, copy it to the emulator, and launch it. You should see something like this once it's done:"

This stage failed. Thus, there were no signs for packaging, copying to the emulator, launching. What I could see is that the android emulator starts with no sign to my application. I tried to look for the app in the android apps, it wasn't there.

I thought that I found a workaround, as follows: When I exited the emulator, I reached back to Visual Studio, with the "Select Device" window. This time, the window appeared with a device name "emulator-5554" highlighted in green, but only for about 1 second (this device name or any other besides "Monodroid" didn't appear when I tried to run the application at the beggining by clicking CTRL-F5). If within this 1 second I clicked OK, I saw these massages one after the other:

"Packaging application.."
"Waiting for device.."

This last message never ended, until I closed the window. This resulted in another popup window which said:

"There were deployment errors. Continue?"

When I clicked Yes, I reached this "MonoDroid does not support running the previous version.  Please ensure your solution builds before running or debugging it."
When clicked No I reached the above mentioned deployment error message.

When I waited for the emulator-5554 device to disappear after 1 second, all I could do is quiting the "Select Device" window which ended with the same deplyoment error message.

What can I do to make it work?
Someone can help, please? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Add the android tools directory to your path in environment settings.  Then run the command: "adb kill-server" to restart the adb process. Then run "adb devices" and make sure you see your emulator.  If you don't see it, then close the emulator down and restart it.

Try the build again, if that fails you could cd to the bin directory where your .apk file is located and try running "adb install your-app.apk" to install your apk manually to the emulator.

Comment: Also, after reading your post closer I had this thought: ensure that the emulator you are running matches what is defined in your manifest file.  You should have something like this in your manifest:  `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" 
          android:targetSdkVersion="12"
           />`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
First open the emulator and create your device and start and wait(for first time it needs about 15 minuts)
It will deploy in best way , if not use the USB cab